# Why does this user have a 0% accept rate, when many of his/her questions have accepted answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accept-rate

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146780/unknown-yahoo) has a 0% accept rate, but many of his/her questions have accepted answers. Is this a bug?

Comment: Did he recently just accept a bunch of answers?

Comment: According to the alt-text, only 19 of his 25 questions are eligible too...

Comment: I agree, I looked the user has 25 questions asked and has accepted answers on at least 11. This despite the fact that the acceptance rate says the user has "accepted 0 of 19 eligible"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears as though this user has gone on an "accept" binge in just the last hour - I'd guess it's a caching issue. (the % accepted query is a batch thing, AFAIK)

Comment: This user has mended his/her ways. Obviously the "accept rate" feature is doing it's job!

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the user just started accepting answers. The acceptance percentage is heavily cached, and for both the questions of theirs I just checked, it was today when the answer was accepted, including for the [oldest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233365) question they have with an accepted answer. The other question I checked can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350041).

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think Troggy is right. I looked at the user's recent activity, and he/she only received the "scholar" badge 16 minutes ago.